# Redirect to an external link not working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to make a redirect to an external link. In Laravel 4.2 I just do:

```
return Redirect::away($external);
```

and it works.

But in Laravel 5.3 I am having challenges. The old style (Laravel 4) redirect is not working, neither are the following:

```
 return redirect($external);
 return redirect()->away($external);
```

There's no error but nothing happens either.

Any idea?

Comment: `return redirect()->away($external);` would be the way to go. Can you provide the specific code you are trying to run?

Comment: @Josh I discovered where the problem was. There was a `return` on `redirect` but didn't have a `return` on calling method. Problem solved. Thanks.